# How does jumping work in Descent 2nd Edition?

Tags: descent

In Descent: Journeys in the Dark, 2nd Edition, the rules state:

> Figures cannot jump over a pit space.

I never saw jumping mentioned anywhere else in the rules. How does jumping work and where is it defined?

This is not the same as [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/in-descent-can-heroes-jump-over-arbitrary-tiles-or-just-pits) question, as that question is dealing with the 1st edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot jump in Descent 2nd Edition. I believe this statement is in the rulebook to notify First Edition players that this is a difference in the editions: you can no longer spend extra movement to jump across a pit you are aware of.